# Dynamically setting value of `grid-template-columns` css property

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Let's begin with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ilyamilosevic/7nxv8cof/. So, in the example we are setting value of `grid-template-columns` to `repeat(${n}, 1fr)` where `n` is the number of columns. After opening devTools in Chrome (or in Firefox, doesn't matter) we see that the value of previously mentioned property is actually the long alternative (`grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr`) to laconic `repeat(10, 1fr)` if `n = 10`. You can call it a nit picking but I am interested why is it happening.

Additional info:

- Windows;
- Chrome 57.0.2987.110 32-bit;
- Firefox 52.0.1 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the steps of the specification you see

> [`setProperty`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty)
>   5. Let component value list be the result of [parsing](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#parse-a-css-value) value for property property.

then

> [parsing](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#parse-a-css-value)
>   1.Let list be the value returned by invoking [parse a list of component values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#parse-a-list-of-component-values) from value.

then

> [parse a list of component values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#parse-a-list-of-component-values)
>   1. Repeatedly [consume a component value](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#consume-a-component-value) until an  is returned, appending the returned values (except the final ) into a list. Return the list.

almost there

> [consume a component value](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#consume-a-component-value)
>   Otherwise, if the current input token is a <function-token>, [consume a function](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#consume-a-function) and return it.

and finally

> [consume a function](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#consume-a-function)
>   Create a function with a name equal to the value of the current input token, and with a value which is initially an empty list.
>   Repeatedly consume the next input token and process it as follows:
>   <)-token>
>       Return the function.
>   <EOF-token> This is a parse error. Return the function.
>   anything else
>       Reconsume the current input token. Consume a component value and append the returned value to the function’s value.

in short, when it is a function it gets executed and its result is assigned.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, maybe that's a moment from now on I need to start reading specifications! Thanks.